Injectivity of Quadratic Matrix Function
Fix positive integers $D,N$ and $d$.
Let $A$ and $W$ be $N\times N$ and $d\times d$ matrices respectively.  Consider the map
$$
\begin{aligned}
f:\mathbb{R}^{N\times d} & \to \mathbb{R}^{N\times d}\\
X& \mapsto AXW + X.
\end{aligned}
$$
What conditions do we need on $A$ and on $W$ to guarantee that $f$ is injective?

So far what I have is: If $W$ is the identity matrix then we only want that $(A+I_{N\times d})$ has full column rank...but I have no idea how to handle the general case (ie when W is general)

Do we have $N=D$?

Since $f$ is linear one has to find a condition  under which the only image of $0$ is $0$.

The given function $f$ is a linear function between finite dimensional vector spaces. Hence, it is injective if and only if $\ker f = \{0\}$. We can simply vectorize and check:
$$ ( + A⊗W)\operatorname{vec}(X) = 0 ⟺ (A⊗W)\operatorname{vec}(X) = -\operatorname{vec}(X)$$
Which is an eigenvalue equation. The eigenvalues of the Kronecker Product $A⊗W$ are precisely $(λ_iμ_j)_{i=1:N, j=1:d}$, where $λ_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $μ_j$ are the eigenvalues of $W$.
Criterion ①: $f$ is invertible if and only if $-1∉σ(A)⋅σ(W)$
However, getting the eigenvalues might be impractical. Alternatively, $( + A⊗W)$ is guaranteed to be invertible if $‖A⊗W‖_2<1$ (see Neumann Series). The spectral norm is equal to the largest singular value. Like with the eigenvalues, the singular values of $A⊗W$ are the products of the singular values of $A$ and $W$.
Criterion ②: $f$ is invertible if $‖A‖_2 ⋅ ‖W‖_2<1$.
